# Grid column width calculation Windows 10 when ColumnDefinition Width="*"

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10

In Windows 8.1 I have a working Xaml Grid code that creates three columns two on the very left and right and one in the middle that fills the space.

```
<Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid" DataContext="{Binding}" MinHeight="40" Width="200"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
</Grid>
```

In Windows 10 the third column does not show up. By changing the Width of the second column to "Auto" I can see all the columns but that's not the UI design that I need.

Comment: Did you put something in the third column? If it's empty, the Auto width will be 0 and it won't be visible.

Comment: Yes, both column 0 and 2 have valid content.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like maybe the parent of the Grid is wider than you're expecting so the Grid is getting clipped on the right.  Can I see more of the Xaml that holds the Grid?  You can also check by setting the Grid's HorizontalAlignment to Right to try and figure out where the right edge of its parent is.  If you're using VS2015RC you can use the "Live Visual Tree" tool while F5 debugging under Debug->Windows->Live Visual Tree.

Comment: I've set the width of the grid. I just forgot to copy that part to the question.
I've seen some other strange behaviors from other XAML layout panels specially RelativePanel. I guess I just need to wait for RTM.

Comment: I think setting the HorizontalAlignment to Stretch will force any element to bet the width of its parent and ignore what you set for Width, MinWidth, and MaxWidth.